# Tree growing algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, if-statement

I am trying to write a tree growing algorithm where Trees go through 2 cycles of growth every year. The first growth cycle occurs during the spring, when it doubles in height. The second growth cycle occurs during the summer, when its height increases by 1 meter.

The problem I have is that Now, a new Tree is planted at the onset of spring. Its height is 1 meter. I want to find the height of the tree after N  growth cycles?

I was doing some research on recursive functions where the function is calling it self. I here it makes the code you write more elegant and simple then while loops. I am having problems execute this function though

```
n = input('How long would you like the tree to for?: ')


def cycle(n):
 if n == 0:
    n = + 1
    return n
    print '/n' # The reason for all the '/n' is just for neatness. 
    print('The tree will be ' + n + 'Ft tall')

 elif n % 2 == 0:
    n = 1 + cycle(n - 1)
    return n
    print '/n'
    print('The tree will be ' + n + 'Ft tall')

 elif n % 2 != 0:
    n = 2 * cycle(n - 1)
    return n
    print '/n'
    print('The tree will be ' + n + ' Ft tall')

 cycle(n)
```

Comment: What is n? Number of cycles or its height? Also, `print`s wont work since you are `return`ing before printing.

Comment: The plan was to let 'n' be how long you would want the tree to grow for in years. But 1year = 2 cycles. summer where the tree grow +1m and the spring where the tree *2 its height.

Comment: You are getting the final height from user so what you want to return? In how many cycles will tree reach/get close to that height (`n`)? In OP you said "I want to find the height of the tree after N growth cycles" but in code, you are getting the height itself which leads some confusion -at least for me-.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable *n* also conflates height of the tree with the cycles of growth. You should instantiate distinct variables for distinct measurements! Also, *n* is being modified at all levels of the stack, likely causing the erroneous output.

Recursive calls can make algorithms more elegant, but they are also almost always less intuitive than the non-recursive solution. My recommendation to a beginning student is to solve the problem iteratively and then translate the iterative algorithm to its recursive form.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe a recursive function is the best way to go for this program. Also, for your first line, you should use int(input()), not just input(). Although, if you do wish to use recursive functions, here is my code for the program:

```
n = int(input("How many years does the tree grow? "))
def cycle(s, height):
    height *= 2
    height += 1
    s -= 1
    if s != 0:
        cycle(s, height)
    else:
        print("Your tree was", height, "meters.")
cycle(n, 1)
```